# How to resolve Status: 400 error with Nodejs

Tags: node.js

> I am getting Status 400 error with below Nodejs code
> This is trying to send https post request to abc.xyz on port 12345
> I am unable to figure what is wrong here.
> Although I am not Nodejs expert

```
const https = require('https');

const options = {
  hostname: 'abc.xyz',
  port: 12345,
  path: '/test/',
  method: 'POST',
  json: true,
  rejectUnauthorized: false
};


exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
        let body = '';
        console.log('Status:', res.statusCode);
        console.log('Headers:', JSON.stringify(res.headers));
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        res.on('data', (chunk) => body += chunk);
        res.on('end', () => {
            console.log('Successfully processed HTTPS response');
            // If we know it's JSON, parse it
            if (res.headers['content-type'] === 'application/json') {
                body = JSON.parse(body);
                // console.log('Body: ' + body);
            }
            callback(null, body);
        });
    });
    req.on('error', callback);
    // req.write(JSON.stringify(event.data));
    //console.log(event.data);
    req.end();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only host these applications on localhost when testing.

You also need an `app.listen(LOCALHOST:PORT);`
A simple Nodejs tutorial will give you a deeper explanation.
This is a simple node server running on localhost 8080, no one else can see it.

```
var http = require('http');

//create a server object:
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.write('Hello World!'); //write a response to the client
  res.end(); //end the response
}).listen(8080); //the server object listens on port 8080
```

Comment: > Thanks. But I need to make https POST request to remote URL abc.xyz. At the other end, it says "Received POST request but does not has any readable content". So I am believing there is nothing in the 'body' to be processed and hence it says 400 says. I am not sure though how to correct this in above lines of code.

Comment: No, because abc.xyz is not localhost:PORT, the requests won't work. Make it listen on localhost:PORT and it will probably work.
Note: localhost:PORT can be anything, I use localhost:3000 or 8000. Please vote up or mark as helpful if it helped you!